# Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : Timeout was reached: Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds

Tags: r

So I've got a list of `"Player"` objects, each with an ID, called `players` and I'm trying to reach a web JSON with information related to the relevant ID, using JSONlite.

The HTML stem is: 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/element-summary/'

I need to access every players respective page.

I'm trying to do so as follows:

```
playerDataURLStem = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/element-summary/'

for (player in players) {
  player_data_url <- paste(playerDataURLStem,player@id,sep = "")
  player_data <- fromJSON(player_data_url)

  # DO SOME STUFF #

}
```

When I run it, I'm getting the error `Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : Timeout was reached: Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds`. This error is produced at a different position in my list of players each time I run the code and when I check the webpage that is causing the error, I can't see anything erroneous about it. This leads me to believe that sometimes the pages just take longer than 10000 milliseconds to reply, but using

```
options(timeout = x)
```

for some `x`, doesn't seem to make it wait longer for a response.

For a minimum working example, try:

```
playerDataURLStem = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/element-summary/'

ids <- c(1:540)
for (id in ids) {
    player_data_url <- paste(playerDataURLStem, id, sep = "")
    player_data <- fromJSON(player_data_url)
    print(player_data$history$id[1])
}
```

Comment: Have you already found the solution to make the time longer? I am also seeking for the answer, will be very appreciated if you could share some experience

Comment: I get an error for `id = 532`: `Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 404.` (page not found).

Answer (score 2):

options(timeout= 4000000) is working for me .try increasing value of timeout to higher number